# Can I use Solr for analytics data of 10 million rows

Tags: database, solr

I want to store static data, but I don't know which database is faster for storing 10-100 millions rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is not the correct form for this question. I would suggest padding our your requirements and posting this over at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

**Generally** speaking all DB platforms will hold a 100 million rows of data no problem at all - given careful consideration to the design on the platform of choice, i.e. the correct indexes etc

What I am saying here is the correct mechanism to store this data will depend on your requirements, for example StackOverflow are known for using a mix of technology from SQl Server to Redis. Pick the correct tool for the job based on requirements, and until we know your requirements a little better it is hard to provide an overview of each.